# Cookie restriction mode not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

I'm using magento 1.9 and I'm trying to set up the cookie restriction mode to display the cookie notice. I have everything enabled and appears set up correctly but the cookie notice doesn't display, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like [this](https://cookieinfoscript.com/) is way better looking and nicer alternative with a lot of customization possibilities.

Just add the script in: `System->Configuration->Design->Footer->Miscellaneous HTML`

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookieinfo"
    src="//cookieinfoscript.com/js/cookieinfo.min.js">
</script>
```

(But check the link for more customization)